# Не работает скрипт отправки формы на почту

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Не могу понять в чем проблема, помогите

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".callback-form").submit(function() {
    if (document.form.name.value == '' || document.form.phone.value == '' || document.form.email.value == '') {
      valid = false;
      return valid;
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../mail/mail.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      $('.callback').fadeIn();
      $(this).find('input').val('');
      $('.callback-form').trigger('reset');
    });
    return false;
  })
})
```

```html
<section class="callback">
  <div class="callback-popup">
    <form class="callback-form" name="callback-form">
      <button class="close">
                    <img src="img/close.svg" alt="Закрыть">
                </button>
      <h3 class="title">Заказать обратный звонок</h3>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" class="input-name" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
        <input type="email" class="input-email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="phone" class="input-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон">
      </div>
      <button class="button">Заказать звонок</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
<?php
$recepient = "lyubadmitry2@gmail.com";
$siteName = "Womazing";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$message = "Вам заказали обратную связь: \nИмя: $name \nПочта: $email \nТелефон: $phone";

$pageTitle = "Заявка на обратный звонок с сайта \"$siteName\"";
mail($recepient, $pageTitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");

?>
```

Comment: А что именно не работает? Вы используете правильный url? Я просто не совсем понимаю что за точки в начале урла)

Comment: Ну и вместо document.form.name.value попробуйте использовать $('.callback-form').find('input[name="name"]').val()
Точно также для остальных полей ввода.

Comment: Я новичек в JS) я просто думал, что нужно выйти из папки js и войти в папку mail. Поэтому я и поставил ..

Comment: Все равно на почту не приходит сообщение

Comment: попробуйте на `button` `type="submit"` поставить

Comment: Все равно не работает